# How to get html form to see textbox data in js

Tags: html, forms

I have a form with 3 entries and an input submit button. One field is a textbox that prompt a numerical entry and the other 2 are selection fields. After many attempts I was finally able to get the browser to pick up on the selection options, however when i console.log it its still not seeing the numerical entry.

```js
const submitForm = (event) => {
  const form = document.getElementById('form');
  const data = new FormData(form);
  const dataObject = {};
  for (const [key, value] of data.entries()) {
    dataObject[key] = value;
  };
  console.log(dataObject);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="form" onsubmit="javascript:submitForm();return false;" id="form">
   <div class="dataEntry">
    <div class="grossIncome">
     <label for="grossIncomeEntry">Enter your gross income</label>   
     <input type="number" inputmode="numeric" id="incomeTextBox" placeholder="Gross Income" required>        
    </div>
    <div class="timeframe">
    <label for="perTimeframe">Per</label>
    <select name="dateRange" id="incomeTimeframe">
    <option value="Annual">Annual</option>
    <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option
</select>
   </div>
     <div class="employmentLocation">
     <label for="workingProvince">Where do you work?</label>
     <select name="workingProvince" id="provinces">
     <option value="Ontario">Ontario</option>
     <option value="Quebec">Quebec</option>
    </select>
     </div>
   <button type="submit" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
   </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This operation:

```
new FormData(form)
```

Is essentially creating key/value pairs of form elements/values.  The key is the `name` of the form element, and the value is its current value.

You can observe this when you see the property names in the resulting object being logged to the console.  The property name for the `<select>` value is `"dateRange"`.  When you observe your code, where do you expect that property name comes from?  Given that, what do you expect the property name for the `<input>` value to be and why?

Your `<select>` has a `name`, but your `<input>` does not.  Simply add a `name` to it:

```js
const submitForm = (event) => {
  const form = document.getElementById('form');
  const data = new FormData(form);
  const dataObject = {};
  for (const [key, value] of data.entries()) {
    dataObject[key] = value;
  };
  console.log(dataObject);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form name="form" onsubmit="javascript:submitForm();return false;" id="form">
   <div class="dataEntry">
    <div class="grossIncome">
     <label for="grossIncomeEntry">Enter your gross income</label>   
     <input type="number" inputmode="numeric" id="incomeTextBox" placeholder="Gross Income" required name="incomeTextBox">        
    </div>
    <div class="timeframe">
    <label for="perTimeframe">Per</label>
    <select name="dateRange" id="incomeTimeframe">
    <option value="Annual">Annual</option>
    <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option
</select>
   </div>
     <div class="employmentLocation">
     <label for="workingProvince">Where do you work?</label>
     <select name="workingProvince" id="provinces">
     <option value="Ontario">Ontario</option>
     <option value="Quebec">Quebec</option>
    </select>
     </div>
   <button type="submit" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
   </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: so i noticed that, but I thought that get element by id would pick up on that. Could you add some clarity to that?

Comment: @Reggie: Just think about this logically.  When you observe the resulting object in the console, the property name for the `<select>` value is `"dateRange"`.  When you observe your code, where does that property name come from?  Given that observation, what property name do you expect to be associated with the `<input>` value and why?  `getElementById` has nothing to do with anything here.  Focus on debugging observations, and for any given expectation focus specifically on *why* you have that expectation.  If you can't identify why you expect something then you have no reason to expect it.